# Azure AD SCIM 2.0 roles and appRoleAssignments empty

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, scim2

In Azure AD I setup SCIM which is working great. However for some reason `roles` as well as `appRoleAssignments` are never sent in the body of a SCIM `POST` or `PATCH` request.

As an example, here's the SCIM body for a `POST` request:

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
    ],
    "userName":"testBlaBla@example.com",
    "active":true,
    "displayName":"Test Bla bla",
    "meta": {
        "resourceType":"User"
    },
    "roles":[]
}
```

This test user has been assigned with Directory Roles and Application Roles. An attribute (with default value "n/a") for the appRoleAssignments was added and mapped. And API permissions for read/write Application Role Assignments was added.

**Screenshot of SCIM Attribute mappings with target application**

[image]

**Screenshot of custom added appRoleAssignments attribute**

[image]

How can I get SCIM in Azure AD to also sent Roles and Application Roles information to the target application?

Comment: Following this as I see the same exact issues. Want to be able to get the assigned app roles of a user (multivalued). For now my reseach has found that 

a) custom SCIM attributes, such as your "appRoles" is never transfered
b) When flowing appRoleAssignments to a valid attribute, it exports as a weird serialized XML of the whole sync request from the internal AAD sync engine

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that you are using a mapping of type expression rather than direct and user the appRoleassignment function.

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/customize-application-attributes#provisioning-a-role-to-a-scim-app
2. Select the target attribute that comes out of the box or if you extend the schema follow the format described here, e.g.:

   ```
   urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:2.0:CustomExtensionName:appRoles
   ```

   or

   ```
   urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:CustomExtensionName:2.0:User.appRoles:value
   ```

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/customize-application-attributes#provisioning-a-custom-extension-attribute-to-a-scim-compliant-application